# Complex MySQL query issue

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a somewhat complex mySQL query I am trying to execute. I have two parameters: facility and isEnabled. Facility can have a value of "ALL" or be specific ID. isEnabled can have value of "ALL" or be 0/1.

My issue is that I need to come up with logic that can handle the following scenarios:
        1) Facility = ALL AND isEnabled = ALL 
        2) Facility = ALL AND isEnabled = value
        3) Facility = someID AND isEnabled = ALL
        4) Facility = someID AND isEnabled = value

The problem is that I have several nested IF statements:

```
IF (Facility = 'ALL') THEN
  IF (isEnabled = 'ALL') THEN
    SELECT * FROM myTable
  ELSE
    SELECT * FROM myTable
    WHERE isEnabled = value
  END IF;
ELSE
  IF (isEnabled = 'ALL') THEN
    SELECT * FROM myTable
    WHERE facility = someID
  ELSE
    SELECT * FROM myTable
    WHERE facility = someID AND isEnabled = value
  END IF;
END IF;
```

I would like to be able to combine the logic in the WHERE clause using either a CASE statement or Conditional's (AND/OR) but I am having trouble wrapping my head around it this morning. Currently the query is not performing as it is expected to be.

Any insight would be helpful!
Thanks

Comment: You could just put that logic in your `WHERE` clause and use parenthesis...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  myTable
WHERE
  1=1
  AND (facility  = someID OR Facility  = 'ALL')
  AND (isEnabled = value  OR isEnabled = 'ALL')
```

However, this yields a poor execution plan - it's trying to find one size fits all, but each combination of parameters can have different plans depending on data, indexes, etc.

This means that it is better to build the query dynamically

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  myTable
WHERE
  1=1
  AND facility  = someID  -- Only include this line if : Facility  = 'ALL'
  AND isEnabled = value   -- Only include this line if : isEnabled = 'ALL'
```

I know it can feel dirty to use dynamic queries, but this is a good corner case as to when then really can excel.  I'll go find a spectacularly informative link for you now.  (It's a lot to read, but it's very worth learning from)

Link : [Dynamic Search](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)

Comment: +1 about the poor execution performance re the the 'OR' Optional Pattern

Comment: I guess I should mention this is from a stored procedure and I actually slimmed down the fields. There are 187 columns that are actually in the SELECT statement (not SELECT * FROM)..reading over that link and it seemed like it suggested the whole query be built in the SP. Passing in 187 fields from the code will require some major programming changes..not sure if that will be manageable. Unless I'm seeing something incorrectly?

Comment: It's a trades-and-balances game.  If you have a condition that *sometimes* goes in the WHERE clause, building it dynamically in this way can yield significant benefits.  In terms of the SELECT clause, the benefits are much smaller, though you may still be able to make some optimisation there just based on the parameters you'd se in the WHERE clause.  If you have 187 searchable fields, and so 187 possible WHERE clause entries, you're looking at 187 parameters any way, aren't you?

Comment: Well I figure its best to explore all possible options and review the query performance of each.  What is the syntax for a CASE statement in the WHERE clause for MySQL?

Comment: Also, if Facility = ALL or isEnabled = ALL then I need to exclude them from the WHERE clause so i can return rows regardless of those two columns' values

Comment: You probably wouldn't use CASE, as you can't do this (to my knowledge) `(CASE WHEN x='ALL' THEN field=x ELSE true END) AND (CASE) AND (CASE)`.  That's why my initial example has `AND (? OR ?)`.  If you -really- wanted to use CASE, then it would be `faility = (CASE WHEN Facility='All' THEN facility ELSE someID END)`

Comment: I'll mark this solution as the answer, although its not what I went with..but got my brain working so I could find a solution